# Printing number formatting in excel file from python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have multiple columns of negetive numbers, integers. Some of them has to be in a specific format.

Ex: Input dataframe:

```
Value1 Value2 Value2
1 -5 -50.5
2 35.6 -70
-4 3 -20
```

expected output is

```
Value1 Value2 Value2
1 (5) (50.5)
2 35.6 (70)
-4 3 (20)
```

As you can see only Value2 and Value3 columns have negative values which are displayed in parenthesis.

Now i have tried the below to display the required format and its working fine:

```
formatter = lambda x: '(%s)' % str(x)[1:] if x < 0 else str(x)
pd.options.display.float_format = formatter
df6.head()
```

but when i use the below to print it in excel file It does not follow the required format.

```
df6.to_excel('output.xlsx', index=False)
print('Spreadsheet saved.')
```

I need a way to print this properly in excel output file

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html):

```
df6.applymap(formatter).to_excel('output.xlsx', index=False)
```